# why npm install get excepted modules with package.json?

Tags: npm, npm-install

**my project has the package.json file like this:**

[image]

**There is 41 packages in this file, but after "npm install", the folder "node_modules" has 613 packages, i don't know why, i thought there should only 41 packages in the folder "node_modules".**

Comment: they are not 41 packages, they are 41 packages with 572 dependencies.

Comment: This [blog](https://lexi-lambda.github.io/blog/2016/08/24/understanding-the-npm-dependency-model/#dependency-duplication-and-the-dependency-tree) post will help you to better understand npm's dependency tree.

Comment: @AmiNadimi yeah,now i know it,thank you!

Comment: @Alexander I really appreciate your reply, thank you.

Comment: @RobC Thanks! This blog is very helpful for me!

Comment: you're welcome, but try to remove the image and type in the `package.json` code.

Comment: I really try to post the content as code at first, but  there is a warning: Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.
So i have to post this img, so sorry about that.